# Removing duplicates from an output base on the sum of two numbers

Tags: python, permutation

I'm very new to Python so please be kind!:) I'm just messing about at the moment but I can't find anything specific on this particular issue.

I'm looking to remove duplicates from an output based upon the the sum of two numbers. I have the following lists of numbers and the short code where I can print the numbers that multiply to give 24.

```py
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8

for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if (a * b) == 24:
            print (a, b, a+b)
```

The outcomes here are:

```
3 8 11
4 6 10
6 4 10
8 3 11
```

In the output there are four combinations that give 24, two of which are permutations of each other. Is there any way that I can deduplicate the permutations to get "unique" outputs? One of the ways that I thought to do this was by adding `a+b` and trying to remove the duplicates in output based on this number but I can't think of a way to do this. Anyone got any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: You should investigate ‘itertools’ which can get you permutations in one go.

Comment: You can use set as container which doesn't allow duplicates. `{frozenset((a, b)) for a in A for b in B if a * b == 24}`

Comment: Are the two lists of numbers A and B really the same?

Answer (score 0):

Create a set and store combinations of `(a,b)`,`(b,a)` in it if printing.
Don't print if `(a,b)` already in set:

```
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8

got = set() # collect (a,b) and (b,a) that you printed already to avoid dupes
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if (a * b) == 24:
            if (a,b) in got:
                continue
            got.add((a,b))  # need to add (a,b) and (b,a) to avoid printing 
            got.add((b,a))  # (b,a) after you already printed (a,b)
            print (a, b, a+b)
```

Output:

```
3 8 11
4 6 10
```

---

Lets compare this and [olivn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401081/7505395)s approach - I removed both print statements:

```
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 

def ol():
    res = set()
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if a * b == 24:
                if {a, b} not in res:
                    # print(a, b, a + b)
                    res.add(frozenset((a, b)))

def pa():
    got = set() # collect (a,b) and (b,a) that you printed already to avoid dupes
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if (a * b) == 24:
                if (a,b) in got:
                    continue
                got.add((a,b))  # need to add (a,b) and (b,a) to avoid printing 
                got.add((b,a))  # (b,a) after you already printed (a,b)
                # print (a, b, a+b)
 

from timeit import timeit

print("Olivn:", timeit(ol, number=10000))
print("this: ", timeit(pa, number=10000))
```

Output:

```
Olivn: 0.60943335
this:  0.6066992629999999
```

Comment: Why you add two tuples to set? oO

Comment: @Oli You add `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` so that if you encounter `(b,a)` later, you see you already handled the case `(a,b)` earlier

Comment: Why to not use `frozenset` instead?

Comment: @Oli because this is closest to the original code and you can not modify a frozenset so you cannot use it in this fashion.  There are easier wayss to do the same using itertools.combinations or list comps but thats a bit advanced based on the question posed.

Comment: You don't need to modify it. I've meant that you can insert just single `frozenset` instead of two tuples, because order of elements doesn't matter. And it won't change almost nothing, just replacing one data container with another.

Comment: @Olvin you already posted that as comment so why should I poach that approach? Answer yourself if you want it answered like this?

Answer (score 0):

You may create keep track of the numbers with results as 24 and can avoid the duplicate numbers as follow

```
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
pass_list: list = []

for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if (a * b) == 24 and b not in pass_list:
            pass_list.append(a)
            print (a, b, a+b)
```

**Output**

```
3 8 11
4 6 10
```

---

Just extending @patrick's comparison with 1000000 counts, this answer seems bit more faster.

```
Olivn: 9.081725899999999
Patrick:  7.241247899999999
this:  5.5779484

Olivn: 9.3896246
Patrick:  7.960243800000001
this:  5.6804922

Olivn: 10.6548058
Patrick:  8.282727000000001
this:  7.1877061

Olivn: 11.1385039
Patrick:  9.226674899999999
this:  8.4106494
```

---

```
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8 

def ol():
    res = set()
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if a * b == 24:
                if {a, b} not in res:
                    # print(a, b, a + b)
                    res.add(frozenset((a, b)))

def pa():
    got = set() # collect (a,b) and (b,a) that you printed already to avoid dupes
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if (a * b) == 24:
                if (a,b) in got:
                    continue
                got.add((a,b))  # need to add (a,b) and (b,a) to avoid printing 
                got.add((b,a))  # (b,a) after you already printed (a,b)
                # print (a, b, a+b)
 

def pr():
    pass_list: list = []

    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if (a * b) == 24 and b not in pass_list:
                pass_list.append(a)
                #print (a, b, a+b)


from timeit import timeit

print("Olivn:", timeit(ol, number=1000000))
print("Patrick: ", timeit(pa, number=1000000))
print("this: ", timeit(pr, number=1000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

@PatrickArtner decided to not follow my recommendations in comments under his answer so here is correct *(imho)* way how you can apply `set` *(and `frozenset` as well)*:

```py
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8
B = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8

res = set()
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if a * b == 24:
            if {a, b} not in res:
                print(a, b, a + b)
                res.add(frozenset((a, b)))
```

Comment: Using frozensets takes more time to create the underlying datastructures for the set instead of using simple tuples. See the time comparison of yours vs mine - mine is slightly faster. I store two tuples where you store one frozenset - not sure which one uses more memory - timewise yours takes longer then using tuples.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, yes, yours faster few milliseconds on 100k iterations, that's why i've added *imho*. I just wanted to show both python built-in set structures and all benefits you can get using sets, also it's a bit more compact.